# How to update a column in data page after we get the results from case execution?

Tags: pega

I want to update a column by name A which is the output of the case.
Can we use activity for this?
What is the best way to achieve?

Comment: Please be more specific or provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

I used activity to perform this.
In activity I called a method "Obj-Open" with appropriate  step page to get the details of the data page. We need to pass the appropriate key to fetch the particular record.
Then call the Property-Set method in the next step of the activity with appropriate  step page. Here set the target and source properties accordingly.
In the next step of the activity call the Obj-Save method with appropriate  step page.
Please let me know if there is any other better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try using savable datapage in your Flow Action post processing. See my example in the attached screenshot.
[image: Savable DataPage]